# Toggle icon switch from fas fa-lock-open to fas fa-lock using addEventListener click

Tags: javascript, html, web-frontend

```
const newLock = document.createElement("i"); 
        newLock.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-lock-open") 
        newLock.setAttribute("id", color + "lock");
```

how can i toggle icon switch from fas fa-lock-open to fas fa-lock using addEventListener click ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check class and compare it, and toggle it based on that. Below is the code how you can do it. Just removed the **i** instead of button.

```
<html>
<body class="body">
  Hello
</body>
</html>
<script>
function load(){
  const newLock = document.createElement("button"); // put I here I just added so that I can use click event
  newLock.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-lock-open") 
  newLock.setAttribute("id", "lock");
  newLock.innerHTML = 'H';
  document.body.append(newLock);
  newLock.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  let i = document.getElementById(e.srcElement.id);
  if(i.getAttribute('class') === 'fas fa-lock-open'){
     i.removeAttribute("class", "fas fa-lock-open");
     i.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-lock");
  }else{
    i.removeAttribute("class", "fas fa-lock");
    i.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-lock-open");
  }
 
  });
}
load();
</script>
```